# Control instances of specific CCSprites with separate class file in Cocos2d

Tags: xcode, ios, cocos2d-iphone, action, ccsprite

I have just started working on my first cocos2d ios app.

I am very used to creating games in Game Maker, in which everything is simpler, and would like some help on creating separate .m/.h class files that contains functions that will affect all instances of a specific CCSprite. Obviously different class files for different CCSprites are needed.

In game maker, objects have code applied to them, and when i want something to happen when an instance is created its pretty easy, by just adding code to the create event.

In xcode i can't think how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go would be to subclass CCSprite.  Check out this guide for more info:

[http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:sprites](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3asprites)

Separate classes may also not be necessary, consider just having different initiators.  Here is an example of a CCSprite subclass that can make both minions and evil rabbits:

```
BadGuySprite *minion = [[BadGuySprite alloc] initAMinion];
BadGuySprite *evilRabbit = [[BadGuySprite alloc] initAEvilRabbit];
```

BadGuySprite.h

```
#import "cocosd.h"

@interface BadGuySprite: CCSprite
{
   int lifebar;
}

+(id) initAMinion;
+(id) initAEvilRabbit;

@end
```

BadGuySprite.m

```
#import "BadGuySprite.h"

@implementation BadGuySprite

- (id)initAMinion{
        self = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"minion.png"];
        lifebar = 1000;
        return self;
}
- (id)initAEvilRabbit{
        self = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"rabbit.png"];
        lifebar = 1;
        return self;
    }

@end
```

Comment: Why did you add the "+" on the id's of the header file?